# multiple textview in a row

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, row

It's a very simple question but I dont get how to do it.
I have a listview adapter and a xml row to display each row.
I want to display 3 textview in a single row. This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txtElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px"
        android:textColor="#000000">
    </TextView>
      <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txtElement2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px"
        android:textColor="#000000">
    </TextView>
      <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txtElement3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px"
        android:textColor="#000000">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the text to be displayed like this:

txt1     txt2     txt3

And this is my adapter code (but I guess the problem is in the XML):

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtElement);
    tv.setText(currentElement.getTitle());          

    TextView tv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtElement2);
    tv2.setText(currentElement.getAuthor());            

    TextView tv3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtElement3);
    tv3.setText(""+currentElement.getNumPost());
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change orientation `android:orientation="horizontal"` of LinearLayout.

**EDIT**

***And how if I would like to display it like: txt1 in one line and txt2 txt3 in a second line?***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And how if I would like to display it like:

txt1 in one line and  txt2 txt3 in a second line?

Comment: I've updated my answer for this: txt1 in one line and txt2 txt3 in a second line.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to only change the orientation from vertical to horizontal.